# Visual Studio c# project to Monodevelop ResolveKeySource Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monodevelop

I have developed a c# project using Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 10. Now I want to use this project with Monodevelop in Ubuntu 18.04. I opened the project with Monodevelop and tried to build it but I got the following error. How can I solve it? Thanks.

```
/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB4018: The "ResolveKeySource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: X509Certificate is immutable on this platform. Use the equivalent constructor instead.
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.String fileName, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <2703bbaa0a6e4686b6033c2dddb1a363>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveKeySource.ResolveManifestKey () [0x000e4] in <f6dbc5d4497740418a0ffd4a9d5d751e>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveKeySource.Execute () [0x00008] in <f6dbc5d4497740418a0ffd4a9d5d751e>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x00029] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0  (MSB4018) (register-programmer)
```

Comment: I had a similar issue and it came down to installing missing modules. How big is your project? Can you create a new project on monodevelop and port it in pieces? That's how I found out which part of my project was contributing to the error.

Comment: Problem is fixed. I search through menus and found out that either disabling "Sign the ClickOnce Manifest" option in signing tab in properties of the project or disabling "Enable ClickOnce security settings" option in security tab in properties of the project (or both) had solved the issue.

Comment: Then post an answer. Someone, somewhere, somewhen, will be interested to know the solution. When searching for questions, the items marked as answered are looked at first.